# How do you bind a JSON String into GWT labels?

Tags: json, gwt, binding, bind

I'm newbie in GWT world and I wonder if it's possible in JAVA to bind a JSON String into a GWT label like using Editors but without POJO or interface. (*For example :* using JSON keys after parsing or other annotation in Html doc.) 
I googled but I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

[JSONValue.parseLenient(java.lang.String jsonString)](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/json/client/JSONParser.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) ???  From gwt 2.5

Comment: Yes, after that I have to Get each values with their keys but that was boring when you have many labels. I look for frameworks that automaticaly retreive each value. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: No framework has been designed like that.What if we want to create buttons with those strings ??again a new framework??

Comment: see this ,may usefull .https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/JSON

Answer (score 0):

```
        final JSONObject reqData = new JSONObject();


                reqData.put("sessionId", new JSONString("sessionidvalue"));


            Label label=new Label();
            JSONValue jsonValue=reqData.get("sessionId");

    label.setText(jsonValue.toString());

RootPanel.get().add(label);
```

Comment: Yes, I currently use this method but when I have a lot of label that was boring to get each values. It will be cool if a framework could retreive automaticaly data from JSON with the same name as the label.

Comment: @Nairo then you have to use a POJO and bind it by using editor

Comment: But I have to find a method without using POJO or interface. I wonder if it's possible... Thanks for your help :)